# Exclude certain mail addresses from google group members (using google apps & outlook)

Tags: microsoft-outlook, distribution-list

I have created groups in google apps to act as distribution lists. Most of the users use outlook as a client. The problem that I am facing is that sometimes a user might want to send a mail to the entire group but one. I have tried browsing for hours now to find a way to achieve this.

In Outlook, if you create a group then you have the option of expanding and viewing/editing the list but since google apps' way of doing it is using a group wide email address, I find it difficult to understand a way to achieve this.

Comment: As you pointed out, the two methods are incompatible, so it is not possible.